# pass file stream for model processing in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, sails.js, crud

I have custom Create method I am trying to add for my `Founder` model in my Sails.js Application. The Application includes files and normal form fields. Following the advice of this [tutorial](http://www.shanestillwell.com/2014/04/14/essential-nodejs-development-concepts-p1/).
I am trying to offload a lot of controller code into the `Founder` model for processing. This makes something a little awkward and results in the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stream' of undefined
```

This is the result of this line in my model function:

```
createFromForm: function(opts, cb){
  var id = opts.id;
  var params = opts.params;
  var newFilename = opts.avatartwo._files[0].stream.filename;
```

In the fourth line. Now in the controller the analogous code would be, following Sails syntax:

var newFilename = opts.req.file('avatartwo')_files[0].stream.filename;

I tred simply writing the result of `req.file('avatartwo')` into an option I passed into the model function via:

```
var opts = {
    params: params,
    id: id,
    avatartwo: req.file('avatartwo')
  };
```

Although this seems problematic, but because I am not the most informed on the subject, I do not know why. I could appreciate some elucidation here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To handle file upload in `sailsjs` use following code.

```
   var uploadedFile = req.file('some_file').upload({
    dirname: 'path to store the file',/* optional. defaults to assets/uploads I guess*/
    saveAs: 'new file name', /* optional. default file name */
    maxBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024 //5 MB
}, function(err, uploadedFiles) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json(500, err);
    } else if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
        // handle if no files were uploaded  
    } else {
        // do processing with file descriptor available at  uploadedFiles[0].fd
        //  pass to model in your case
        var opts = {
                params: params,
                id: id,
                avatartwo: uploadedFiles[0].fd
        };

    }
});
```